# Compare array if particular key is same within both array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key, compare

I have two arrays both are two dimensional. I am comparing spreadsheet rows with DB rows. array key for both arrays are same.

### array from DB fetch

```
$array1 = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 1
        [fname] => abc
        [lname] => deg
        [phone] => 123456789
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 2
        [fname] => jkl
        [lname] => xyz
        [phone] => 987654321
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 3
        [fname] => pqr
        [lname] => stu
        [phone] => 111111111
    )
```

### array created from spreadsheet

```
$array2 = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 1
        [fname] => abc
        [lname] => deg
        [phone] => 4444444
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 3
        [fname] => pqr
        [lname] => stu
        [phone] => 111111111
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 4
        [fname] => aaa
        [lname] => bbb
        [phone] => 9999999
    )
```

Now I want only those key and value for specific user which are different.

For example : for uid=1, only phone should display. for uid=2, entire array should display. for uid=3, none(blank array) should display.

I have used array_diff() and it worked fine. but problem is that my code compare consequently (ir-respetive of uid).
I want uid of array1 to be compare with uid of array2.

Comment: Do both arrays have the same number of sub-arrays?

Comment: count can be different in both arrays.

Comment: array1 can can have count 50. array2 can have count 45.
keys will be always same for both array. I mean total 4 key(uid,fname,lanme,phone) for each sub-array.

Answer (score 2):

I would reindex the arrays with the uid and then compare:

```
$new1 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $value){
    $new1[$value['uid']] = $value;
}
$new2 = array();
foreach ($array2 as $value){
    $new2[$value['uid']] = $value;
}
$diff = array();
foreach ($new1 as $key => $value){
    //compare $value with $new2[$key]
    if (isset($new2[$key])){
        $diff[$key] = array_diff($value, $new2[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to compare if email_id is same for both array instead of uid?

Comment: First, you'd have to include email_id in your arrays. Then you would check the diff array and see if there were any differences generated for email_id just the same as you would for phone or anything else.